# App start up delay

Tags: android-activity, transactions, launch, android

I am developing an application. The flow and the task performed in the activities of app is as follows:

**1) Splash screen** - **A.** In Async Task 1st Download a Image from server then Create data base
                   **B.** From post of Async A call Async B for Push Notification registration
                   **C.** From post of Async B call Async C to check a flag -

```
If flag Screen2 == 1 {
    If flag Screen3 == 1{
        go to screen 4
    } else {
        go to Screen 3
    }
} else {
    go to screen 2
}
```

**2) Screen 2** - In onCreate(): **A.** Call some web services for registration. **B.** Set Flag of screen 2 completion to 1.

**3) Screen 3** - In onCreate(): **A.** Call some web service. **B.** Set Flag of screen 3 completion to 1.

**4) Screen 4** - This is Home Screen. In onCreate(): **A.** Call some web services **B.** Register Broadcast Receiver **C.** Start two services

**The issue is:** When i install app it runs ok. But when i close/kill app then on click of icon the app start up delays when flag Screen2 == 1. also when Screen3 == 1.

I am not getting why my application behavior is like this.

Please provide your valuable suggestions and guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens during the delay?

Comment: Thats what i am not getting. Just after click on app icon, the app icon is disable or becomes fade and after around 30 seconds app starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where you are getting the flags?
If it is from database the save and retrieve it from preferences.

Call all the web services in Threads or in background.

Also start your all services in methods and do task in services in Thread or in background.

For shared preference have a look on following links:

[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Link 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

[Link 3](http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146)

And for Background task:

[Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

[Link 2](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/what-is-asynctask-in-android/)

[Link 3](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fos%2FAsyncTask.html&ei=XpxYVIWONcyWuATwroGwDw&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&bvm=bv.78677474,d.c2E)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are doing webservice calls synchronously in onCreate.
Any http call in onCreate should be asynchronous(use a thread or use libraries like android volley - http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: I am calling all the web services in async task.

Comment: what about push notification registration?

Comment: That is also in async task.

Comment: need more info - you can actually put debug points or more logs to identify where the delay is..